# Jdeveloper 11g log window disappeared

Tags: jdeveloper, log-viewer

I am trying to reach log window to see what happens backround. how can I open and view?
there is nothing when I click **View -> Log**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if removing the windowinglayout.xml file from C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1\o.ide helps.